# youtube-dl unable to download audio how to resolve that issue?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

```
./youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVqBLRhC9UzGX1BRbF53zsJE8Jw_eiLRK
```

It produce following output with warning

```
[youtube:playlist] PLVqBLRhC9UzGX1BRbF53zsJE8Jw_eiLRK: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Fear Files
[youtube:playlist] PLVqBLRhC9UzGX1BRbF53zsJE8Jw_eiLRK: Downloading page #1
[youtube:playlist] PLVqBLRhC9UzGX1BRbF53zsJE8Jw_eiLRK: Downloading page #2
[youtube:playlist] playlist Fear Files: Downloading 223 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 223
[youtube] R8lNWOGJ5cg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] R8lNWOGJ5cg: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] R8lNWOGJ5cg: Extracting video information
[youtube] R8lNWOGJ5cg: Downloading MPD manifest
```

```
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
```

```
[download] Resuming download at byte 206757946
[download] Destination: Fear Files - Episode 44 - September 28, 2014-R8lNWOGJ5cg.f137.mp4
```

Because of waring youtube-dl download video without audio. How to solve that issue. I also try command 
youtube-dl -f 22 URL_link but still not work.

Comment: Are you running the latest version? The command `youtube-dl --version` should show '2016.05.01'

Comment: @andrew.46 yes.. 2016.05.01

Comment: I suspect that you don't need the options `-cit -a ff` but I have answered below...

Comment: @andrew.46 -cit -a coz i download by file of url list....

Comment: OIC, I apologise for my misunderstanding. Anyway my answer is given and hopefully it will be useful to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the default behavior of `youtube-dl` where since April 2015 and version 2015.04.26 unless told otherwise `youtube-dl` will download the *best quality video stream* and the *best quality audio stream*.

Two cases arise then:

1. If you have either `ffmpeg` or `avconv` installed the two best quality streams will be downloaded and then muxed together. If the codecs are incompatible together in either flv or mp4 they will be joined in mkv. *This is happening in your case.*
2. If you don't have either `ffmpeg` or `avconv` installed the best quality will be downloaded *that is available as a single file.*

So, you are seeing normal behavior...

**References:**

- [youtube-dl FAQ: Format Selection](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection)

Comment: since many / most ubuntu users who use youtube-dl no doubt also have installed ffmpeg and/or avconv so resultant combo file too often becomes container format .mkv which is clunky especially when using vlc to bounce around the video during playback ... to avoid this I use -f 22 to choose the best mp4 of available formats as shown using -F flag

Comment: Nice that it's normal behavior, but how do you get just the mp4?

Comment: @Costa Perhaps try adding in `-f mp4`

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered the this error. Though it's not a permanent solution, here is what I did. I used the `youtube-dl -f`. This is the option for (`-f`) format. This allows you to specify the format you want to download. To see the formats available for the file (video file), you can use `youtube-dl -F`. This will list all formats available for that particular file. Please note that you have to include the the URL for the video, and write something like this: `youtube-dl -F https://youtu.be/FWxtFTHO1ak`. The picture shows what appears when you run the command in the previous sentence: [image: youtube-dl file formats]

Once you you identify the format you like, for example you can run this command `youtube-dl -f 22 https://youtu.be/FWxtFTHO1ak`. The 22 is the format code for mp4 best quality. I guess this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in UbuntuStudio 16.04 64bits. And because is not posible solved this I install JDonloader, you can install it from:

http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/pool/contrib/j/jdownloader/

in this place you can chose 32 or 64 bits:

[image]

install it, all dependences are ok.

When you copy a link from a video in youtube automatically JDownloader detect, next you can download it

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with using the `--merge-output-format mp4` option:

```
youtube-dl -v --merge-output-format mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYYOUTUBEVIDEO
```

Comment: For latest version 2021.12.17, I need `--merge-output-format mkv` container, mp4 does not give me audio track. I use `-f best`.

Answer (score -1):

I got that message when I downloaded a video and it merged the videos into a mkv file.  After a bit of toying, I used VLC to convert the mkv to mp4 format.  Works swimmingly.